# Update last element of each row in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, `array_one` which is NxM and `array_two` which is NxMx3, and I'd like to change the value of the last element in each row of `array_two`, based on values from `array_one`, like this:

`array_two[i, j, -1] = foo(array_one[i,j])`

where `foo` returns a value based on a computation on an element from `array_one`.

Is there a way to avoid manually looping over the arrays and speed up this process using numpy functions?

Comment: It depends on whether your `foo` can be vectorized.

Comment: Yes, and no. The answer is much depend on how you write the `foo` function. Does it support passing numpy array? for example, `array_two[:,:,-1] = np.sum(array_one)` would work, but `array_two[:,:,-1] = math.sin(array_one)` wouldn't.

Comment: First of all thanks to both of you.
The foo function maps the received value between 0 and 255 based on predefined min/max levels. How could I modify it so that it can vectorized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example showing use of np.vectorize to achieve what you had in mind.

replace square with your foo and you should be in business.

```
import numpy as np

array_3d = np.ones((2,3,2))

array_2d = np.random.randn(2,3)

def square(x):
    return x**2

square_all = np.vectorize(square)

array_3d[:,:,-1] = square_all(array_2d)
print(f'{array_3d[:,:,:]=}')
```